# How would I go about solving this probability question?

Tags: probability

I am currently in year 10 studying GCSE higher maths. My once issue with maths is probability. I have an exam tomorrow and am currently revising by going through past papers, I saw this question and wasn't sure how I'd solve it. Does anyone have an idea?

```
A school has 400 boys and 500 girls.
The probability that a boy is vegetarian is 0.1
The probability that a girl is vegetarian is 0.2
Estimate the total number of vegetarians in the school.
```

Comment: Count the number of vegetarian boys. Count the number of vegetarian girls. Add.

Comment: Yes but how would I count how many there are?

Comment: How many boys must be vegetarian to get that probability?

Comment: Are you asking me @Ross? If so, I don't know this is a past paper set by AQA.

Comment: The probability that a boy is a vegetarian is $P[x\in V\vert\, x\in B]$.  The probability that a student is a boy and a vegetarian is $P[x\in B \textrm{ and } x\in V]$.  These quantities are connected by the conditional probability formula:
$$P[x\in V \vert \, x\in B]=\frac{P[x\in V \textrm{ and } x\in B]}{P[x\in B]}.$$ 
Clearly, $P[x\in B]=\frac{4}{9}$.

Comment: @Unwisdom, clearly I state that I am studying GCSE in year 10 we are not taught any of the above, stated by you. Thanks for the response nevertheless.

Comment: Sorry I misjudged.  I thought that you might have been exposed to that formula already, but I guess not.  Still, you'll get there very soon - see pages 65-66 of your syllabus:
http://www.edexcel.com/migrationdocuments/GCSE2010/UG029981_GCSE_MathsA_Spec_2012.pdf :)

Comment: Nevertheless, my suggestion, renewed by @RossMillikan, stands: there are 400 boys and 10% of the boys are vegetarian hence you should be able to declare that $___$ boys are vegetarian, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimated number of boy vegetarians is $400 \cdot 0.1=40$.

Estimated number of girl vegetarians is $500 \cdot 0.2=100$.

Both sums up to $140$.